# How can I implement pending orders in FIX protocol?

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I have a FIX server which supports open/close positions. Now, I want to add support for pending orders.

In the NewOrderSingle message, there is a field OrdType which defines the type of order, Market,Limit,Stop, etc. I used these ones for position orders. Now I need a parameter for pendings..

I considered adding another parameter to the NewOrderSingle message but wonder if there's a better way..?

Comment: Are you going to clarify the terminology in this question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at the wrong message type.  `ExecutionReport` has an `OrdStatus` field that you can set to "pending new".

`NewOrderSingle` is for a trader to submit an order, and that's *all*.  A trader wouldn't mark his own order as "pending" when he submits it!  The server responds to the trader with an `ExecutionReport` that has the appropriate `OrdStatus`.

Apologies if I'm telling you things you already know.  There's not a lot of context in your question.

Comment: Thanks @Grant. I mean limit orders with the term "pending order". It is a special type of order in the trading platfor mthat we use which is activated when the order's price hits. So, it should be sent using NewOrderSingle.

Comment: I don't understand your question then.  Isn't OrdType=Limit what you need?  Server receives NewOrderSingle/Limit, and acks back a ExecutionReport to the trader.  When the limit price is reached, order is filled, and server sends another ExecutionReport back to the trader to notify him of the status change.

Comment: Sorry, i left out something in my question. Stop and Limit types are used as stoploss and takeprofit indicators in our system. So, in best case, i have to introduce new fields for pending orders.. or do i have another option?

Comment: I think you've reached the limits of my help.  I'm a better programmer than trader, so I'm not sure.

Comment: We need a better definition of what you mean by "pending order". Most people define "pending orders" as limit or stop orders because they don't execute immediately, like a market order. For example, see http://www.investopedia.com/university/how-to-use-meta-trader-4/order-types.asp. I suppose it would also include "if touched" orders as well.